# FullCalendar - updating events via jquery and AJAX

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I have jquery fullcalendar working quite nicely so far, however, I've added some options for the user to be able to filter the events displayed. The approach I've used is just to use AJAX to retrieve the new data to be used in the calendar, empty the existing calendar, and try to rebuild the calendar with the new data.

What's happening at the moment though is that, on page load, the calendar loads events correctly - when I click on a filter, it empties the current events from the calendar, but doesn't load any new events, even though I can see that the JSON returned in the AJAX call contains correctly formatted event data.

There may be an obvious mistake here, or an easier way to do this with a built in method. Any help much appreciated!

```
                   // Store json encoded data in variable
                   var data = <?php echo $events_json ?>;

                   // Pass data to the calendar loader
                   loadCal(data);

                   // Filter event handler
                   $('ul#calendar_filters li a').click(function(){
                        // Retrieve data - have checked this is correctly formatted
                        new_data = $.get($(this).attr('href'));

                        // Empty the calendar of existing data
                        $('#calendar').empty();

                        // Reload calendar with new data set 
                        loadCal(new_data);


                        return false;
                    });

                    function loadCal(data)
                    {
                         $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                            header: {
                                left: 'prev,next today',
                                center: 'title',
                                right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
                            },
                            editable: true,
                            events: data,
                            eventRender: function(event, element) {
                                element.qtip({
                                    content: {
                                        text: formatEvent(event), 
                                        title: {
                                            text: event.title,
                                            button: true
                                        }
                                    },
                                    show: {
                                         event: 'click', // Show it on click...
                                         solo: true // ...and hide all other tooltips...
                                      },
                                    hide: false,
                                    style: {
                                        classes: 'ui-tooltip-light ui-tooltip-shadow ui-tooltip-rounded'
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        });
                    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure it you have already thought about it, but have you considered using checkboxes to display content?

There is a built in method in the docs that is helpful with this.
http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/removeEventSource/

This was my solution...

```
<input type="checkbox" class="selectit" />
<script>
$('.selectit').each(function(){this.checked = true}); //ensures that all boxes are checked

$('input[type:checkbox]').click(function(index){ // Looks at every checkbox when clicked
    $('input:checked').each(function(){ // if checked add the source
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('addEventSources', 'URL_ARRAY_FUNCTION_OR_OBJECT');
    });
    $('input:not(:checked)').each(function(index){ // if not checked remove the source
         $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEventSources', 'URL_ARRAY_FUNCTION_OR_OBJECT');
    });
});
</script>
```